# How to name the repository after / in custom domain?

Tags: github, github-pages

Recently I created a new repository and uploaded my project to it.
Also, I bought new domain and connected it to GitHub Pages.

My domain is [www.maoragai.com](http://www.maoragai.com). I want that the repository that I uploaded will show at the URL [www.maoragai.com/covid19-stats](http://www.maoragai.com/covid19-stats).

How i should do that?

[image]

That's the CNAME record:

[image]

Comment: That's based on the repo name, presumably that's currently `github.com/<yourname>/<yourname>.github.io`. You need to move it to `github.com/<yourname>/covid19-stats`.

Comment: OK, how i need to do that?

Comment: Rename the repo in settings: https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/administering-a-repository/renaming-a-repository

Comment: But' it's already named as covid19-stats.

Comment: In that case I'd guess your CNAME record points to `<yourname>.github.io/covid19-stats`, instead of just `<yourname>.github.io`. FWIW this works fine for me with https://github.com/textbook/salary-stats and https://github.com/textbook/textbook.github.io. See the guidance in https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/working-with-github-pages/managing-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site.

Comment: My CNAME record looks good. Look above, i added the picture of the CNAME.

Comment: Then you'll have to ask GitHub support, as far as I can see that should already be working. I have a CNAME record from `blog` on `jonrshar.pe` to `textbook.github.io` and the pair of repos I shared above work fine.